# Change the look to new SharePoint team sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I just migrated my site collection from SharePoint 2007 on-premise server to office 365 using ShareGate.

Site move was successful and now all my content is in the cloud. The problem is that my site still looks the same only and UI.

1. When I click on a Doc Library the new UI is shown (which is great)
2. If I create a new Team Site the new Modern UI is shown

How do I update all my migrated sites to the new Modern look with all the great looking Web Parts and such.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used Sharegate tool, Here is some useful information for migration from SharePoint 2007 on-premise to Office 365. Link: https://en.share-gate.com/blog/migrate-sharepoint-2007-to-office-365-with-sharegate

**Info:** A lot has changed since SharePoint 2007. The architecture of the platform is very different, but most importantly, there are Site Templates that no longer exist. Sharegate isn't installed on a server and can run from your desktop, it doesn't have access to the same options in the Central Administration. You need a Site Collection to exist at the destination, so that Sharegate can hook on to it.

Here You have to use "**Copy Site Objects**" to migrate all content from **older site collection - SharePoint 2007** to **newer site collection - Office 365**. Reason behind the old look and feel is because you may have migrated whole site collection from SP2007 to Office 365 rather then migrating content.

**Reference:**

- https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-site-migration-move-site
- https://en.share-gate.com/blog/predicting-post-sharepoint-2013-migration-issues